# How are in-app purchases being protected (Ionic, Firebase)?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

There is something I don't understand with in-app purchases.

Scenario: a simple app with some free content and more content available with an in-app purchase.

On start, the app interfaces with the in-app API or checks FB if a purchase has been made and allowing the user access.

What prevents hackers to tweak the app (Ionic or any other js-based app) to always grant access?
More over, on FB I have to allow write access to those fields so that my app can indicate whether or not an in-app purchase has been made. And since the key to my FB is in my app, it can be accessed by anyone!

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Firebase Functions to write to your database instead of your app. This way the fields can be made read-only to prevent hackers from getting access.

The function would be triggered by the Analytics event `in_app_purchase` and the product ID, product name, currency, and quantity are passed as event parameters.

Read about Functions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

List of tracked events: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485

Here's an example function to get you started:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.updateDbOnPurchase = functions.analytics.event('in_app_purchase').onLog(event => {
  const uid = event.user.userId;
  const productId = event.params.productId;

  // Modify to match your database 
  admin.database().ref(`/users/${uid}/products`).push({productId: productId});
});
```